# hello , i got a question that i need to get input from user, the input is a number and digit after digit ,the number can be a doubleWord

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16, emu8086

I am making a program in which I want to take up to a 10 digit number
(4,294,967,296) digit by digit from user and store all of the digits and make
one number of them in EAX.
for example: input = 1 2 3 4, EAX = 1234
i tried with 2 digits for the start and i got some problems and i dont know how
to continue from here.
**I would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance!!**

```
.model small
.STACK 100h
.data  
num dd ?
ten DB 10

.code
.386
   start:
   MOV AX, @DATA
   MOV DS, AX
   MOV AH,1
   INT 21H
   SUB AL,30H
   MOV BH,AL
   MOV AH,1
   INT 21H
   SUB AL,30H
   MOV CH,AL
   
   MOV AL,BL
   MUL ten 
   ADD AL,CH 
   push eax
   call printNum
   MOV AX, 4c00h
   INT 21h
   END start
```

Comment: [Edit] the question to include details on the problem you're having. Is there an error during assembly? Does it not run correctly? The more details you include the more likely you'll get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> MOV AL,BL
> MUL ten 
> ADD AL,CH
> ```

The above would produce the value of your 2-digit number if you would have used the correct register. You have stored the first digit in `BH`, but you're using `BL` here!

> ```
> .386
> push eax
> ```

You are in emu8086. Forget about using 32-bit registers. If you want to work with 32-bit numbers, you'll have to store them in a couple of 16-bit registers. e.g. `DX:AX` where `DX` holds the Most Significant Word and `AX` holds the Least Significant Word.

---

To solve your task of building a 10-digit number up to 4GB-1, next codez will be useful:

### Multiplying the dword in `DI:SI` by 10

```
mov  ax, 10
mul  si         ; LSW * 10 -> DX:AX
mov  si, ax
xchg di, dx
mov  ax, 10
mul  dx         ; MSW * 10 -> DX:AX
jc   Overflow
add  di, ax
jc   Overflow
```

### Adding the new digit `AL=[0,9]` to the dword in `DI:SI`

```
mov  ah, ah
add  si, ax
adc  di, 0
jc   Overflow
```

### Looping until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
Input:
  mov  ah, 01h    ; DOS.GetKeyWithEcho
  int  21h        ; -> AL
  cmp  al, 13     ; Is it <ENTER> ?
  je   Done
  sub  al, '0'    ; From character to digit
  cmp  al, 9
  ja   Invalid

  ...

  jmp  Input
Done:
```

It's important that you decide how you will handle an invalid user input and what you will do for an input that yields a number bigger than 4GB-1. Many programs have been written that overlook this and then at some point mysteriously fail...

Comment: How did you do that nice "Enter" key graphic?

Comment: @puppydrum64 That would be `<kbd>Enter</kbd>`.